# MySQL averaging joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

`salon_ranks`:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| salon_id  |category_id|  user_id  |    rank   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|        10 |         1 |       999 |       1   |
|        10 |         2 |       999 |       1   |
|        10 |         1 |       888 |       5   |
|        10 |         2 |       888 |       5   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

`categories`:

```
+------+-----------+
|  id  |    name   |
+------+-----------+
|   1  |   prices  |
|   2  |   service |
+------+-----------+
```

I'm trying to efficiently get something that looks like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| salon_id  |category_id| AVG(rank) |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|        10 |         1 |       3   |
|        10 |         2 |       3   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

---

What made most sense to me is a query like that:

```
SELECT salon_id, category_id, AVG(rank)
FROM salon_ranks
INNER JOIN categories ON category_id = id
GROUP BY salon_id, category_id
```

But for some reason I don't get the average, but get this instead:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| salon_id  |category_id| AVG(rank) |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|        10 |         1 |       1   |
|        10 |         2 |       5   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Any idea for why it would happen? And what might be the correct query?

---

**I'm sorry, it was my mistake. I got the data from my original tables wrong. 
Really sorry for misleading you :(**

Comment: it should give the correct value. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee5c6/1

Comment: There must be something you're not showing us, because your query is fine. We can't answer if you don't give us a valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now we know your query works fine. But it's good practice to use aliases for tables. 
It's not necessary for your case but it makes your query more readable and scalable.

```
SELECT SR.salon_id, SR.category_id, AVG(SR.rank)
FROM salon_ranks SR
INNER JOIN categories C ON SR.category_id = C.id
GROUP BY SR.salon_id, SR.category_id
```

Comment: Aliases are only necessary if there are ambiguous columns, and in that case the original query would have reported an error.

Comment: @Barmar I didn't find a reason why OP's query return wrong result. So, aliases are the only thing I can suggest him.

Comment: We expect cargo cult programming from questioners, answerers should know better.

Comment: @Barmar I do everything what can I do with the information provided from answer by OP :)

Comment: If you need more information before answering, ask questions in comments. Don't waste time with answers that can't possibly be right.

Comment: Qualifying all column references with table aliases is a best practice; it's good advice. But this answer cannot possibly be related to the question that was asked.

Comment: @spencer7593 I agree, but there is no answer for the question.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee5c6/2

```
SELECT SR.salon_id, SR.category_id, AVG(SR.rank)
FROM salon_ranks SR
INNER JOIN categories C ON SR.category_id = C.id
GROUP BY SR.salon_id, SR.category_id
```